# Jekyll - folders I am adding keep disappearing

Tags: directory, jekyll

I searched a lot to see if this question had already been asked, but perhaps I used the wrong terms. Apologies if the question already exists.

I am teaching myself Jekyll, and I am new to coding, so again, apologies if this has an obvious answer.

Every time that I try to add a folder (I am trying to add an images folder to make them more easily accessible) to the _site directory, it works for a few minutes, and then the folder I added completely disappears. Is there a way to make this stop happening??

I am 100% positive this is a stupid question, but I'd appreciate some help nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: `_site` is the result of your source transformation by Jekyll.
Edit your sources, not the _site folder.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Jekyll! As David Jacquel suggests in his comment, the `_site` folder is created by Jekyll when it builds your site. Jekyll overwrites everything in this folder whenever it runs.

You could create an `images` folder anywhere outside of `_site`. For instance, if you create it in the root directory of your Jekyll site (i.e. beside your `_config.yml` file), and put image files in it, then when Jekyll runs it will copy that entire directory into `_site`.

Then to link to those images in your source files elsewhere, you'd use `{{ site.baseurl }}/images/yourimage.jpg`.

(The `{{ site.baseurl }}` is important if you're publishing on GitHub Pages, or anywhere else where your site lives in a subfolder of your main domain.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should check [jekyll folder structures](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/) , `_site` is generated by jekyll, so do not add new things to there. While at the same time, you should add all your assets under the root folder.

Most time I create a directory named `assets` to store images or other resources.